# Date range filter for manage posts list on edit.php

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, wp-admin

I need to add some custom submenu links to the Posts menu in WordPress admin so content managers can click on a link and get a list of posts from today, yesterday or this month. The default date filter in the WordPress back end filters posts by month only. When you select that filter it produces a URL like

`http:// ..... /wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=post&action=-1&m=201301&cat=0&post_format=0&paged=1&mode=list`

where m is the current month, so 201301 = January 2013. Is it possible to pass edit.php a date in some other format, i.e. a date range? If not, can anyone suggest the best way to generate a list of posts from the last month on the manage posts page?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress support advised me you can use the same parameters on the URL as WP_Query() accepts. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters

You can't pass a date range. The best you can do is pass specific dates.

For example, edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=post&action=-1&m=201301&cat=0&post_format=0&paged=1&mode=list&day=1 will show all posts from the 1st day of the current month.

When I told this to our content manager he was happy just to have a link to a list of posts from yesterday. In case useful to anybody, here's what I'm doing:

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_admin_listing_filters' );

function add_admin_listing_filters() {

    $yest_time = time() - 60 * 60 * 24;
    $yest_year = date('Y', $yest_time);
    $yest_monthnum = date('n', $yest_time);
    $yest_daynum = date('j', $yest_time);

    add_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'Recent - All', 'Recent - All', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?s&year=' . $yest_year . '&monthnum=' . $yest_monthnum . '&day=' . $yest_daynum . '&post_status=publish');
    add_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'Recent - News', 'Recent - News', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?s&year=' . $yest_year . '&monthnum=' . $yest_monthnum . '&day=' . $yest_daynum . '&post_status=publish&category_name=news');

}
```